# Update caused network icon to disappear and wifi connection lost - How can I debug this?

Tags: networking, 21.10

The updates window popped up and I agreed to update the computer. After the upgrade it prompted me to restart my computer so I did. When I logged back in to my user I notice I have no internet. And the network icon is missing from the top right corner.

How can I fix this? I guess the update disabled my network adapter somehow, and the network manager is crashing on boot or something because of it.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is your desktop environment?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10, GNOME.